# How to forecast instance cost based on MAU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We have a service powered by Google AppEngine, and we are trying to forecast the cost of use based on Google pricing informations:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing
- https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#tab=app-engine

Based on estimated MAU for our service we can forecast the cost for most of the AppEngine ressources used (traffic, cloud datastore, ...etc.). However instances is more complicated to estimate as we don't know when they are generated. 
I mean, we do understand the following (instance in automatic mode):

1. Each instance are started and shutdown automatically depending on the volume of access
2. Each instance run for 15min
3. 28 instances per hours are offered by Google

The problem is that we find it very hard to estimate how many instances per hours will be run based on MAU.

Are we missing something?

Thank you in advance for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Instance scaling is non-deterministic based on the number of active users alone. It depends on other factors such as the type of requests made, current system load, scaling parameters, background work (eg. do some requests kick off push tasks running on the same service) etc.

You probably will not be able to get an accurate estimate without doing some kind of time series forecasting. You may want to start by collecting time series data based on actual and/or simulated usage and how it relates to the number of instances created (unique users, requests per unique user, request types, requests times per type etc.)

Data collection aside, questions related to the actual problem of forecasting may be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com.